# How to remove id # column kartik gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

How do I remove id (#) column in kartik gridview?

```
['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: remove this ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

Comment: Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line of gridview

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn']
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove following lines from **'columns' => [ ] array**

```
  [
     'class' => '\kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
  ],
```